# How can I make the exception of Chai.js include stack trace info?

Tags: node.js, exception, stack-trace, chai

I am using Chai.js on Node.
The line `console.log(e)` where e is an exception thrown by Chai.js print something like `expected a to be within 0..3`.
How can I make the exception of Chai.js include stack trace info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer. I can config chai to enable stack trace.
Here's the code on [assertion styles page](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/) of chai.

```
var chai = require('chai');
chai.Assertion.includeStack = true; // defaults to false
```

Comment: It's `chai.config.includeStack = true;` as of Chai version 1.9.1 released on 2014-03-19. See relevant [Chai release notes](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md#user-content-191--2014-03-19) for more information.

Comment: In what file would you put this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Chai.JS.
But if *e* is an *Error* object, you can use the property *stack* of the object to get the stack trace.

The core module "util" may also help you :
http://nodejs.org/api/util.html